# Is it possible to change the type of parens using macros?

Tags: common-lisp

Could macros be used to change the character used for parentheses in the code? For example could `(` and `)` be replaced with `[` and `]`?

Comment: see  http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_set_ma.htm .

Answer (score 2):

There's much more discussion in another question (of which I think this is probably a duplicate), [How to define symbols that will work like ( and ) by symbol macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19319277/how-to-define-symbols-that-will-work-like-and-by-symbol-macro), but it's still worth showing this particular example.  Look at that question for an explanation of how this works.

```
CL-USER> (set-macro-character #\[
                              (lambda (stream ignore)
                                (declare (ignore ignore))
                                (read-delimited-list #\] stream t)))
T
CL-USER> (set-macro-character #\] (get-macro-character #\)))
T
```

```
CL-USER> '[1 2 3]
(1 2 3)

CL-USER> [print 'hello]

HELLO 
;=> HELLO
```

Comment: Joshua, your answer is correct if one wants to **replace** ( and ) with [ and ], but has a problem if one wants to define [ and ] to work exactly like ( and ). In fact, after the above calls, forms like `'(2 3]` cause an error (at least in CCL): `Error: Reader error on #<CCL::RECORDING-CHARACTER-INPUT-STREAM #x30200101EA2D>, near position 6: Unmatched ')' .`

Comment: @Renzo The question does say *"For example could ( and ) be **replaced** with [ and ]?"*  But you make a good point,  **read-delimited-list** reads until a specific character, not until it matches a "list terminating character" (if there were such a class of characters).  So there's no way to make #\\] work like #\\) without changing the behavior of #\\(, since #\\( reads until a matching #\\).