# Can a Lisp read procedure read this and how?

Tags: lisp, grammar, reader

I'm writing a grammar which I intend to implement in a Lisp read procedure, i.e. reading one expression at a time from an input source which is i.e. mutable. Most of the grammar is just like Lisp, but the two pertinent changes are:

Whitespace is read and is part of the resulting syntax. Contiguous whitespace is grouped together like contiguous non-whitespace characters are grouped as identifiers, and the result of reading such a string is a "whitespace object", which stores the exact sequence of characters read. The evaluator ignores whitespace objects when they appear in a list (in other words, if foo is a whitespace object then `(eval '(+ 3 foo 4))` is equivalent to `(eval '(+ 3 4))`), and if it is asked to evaluate one directly, it is self-evaluating.

Secondly, if several tokens other than whitespace tokens appear on the same line, those tokens are collected into a list and that list is the result of the read.

e.g.,

```
+ 3 4 5
(+ 3 4 5)
+ 3 4 (+ 1 4)
(+ 3 4 (+ 1 4))
```

all produce the value 12.

Is it possible to implement this reader as a Lisp read procedure that follows the typical expectations of a read procedure? If so, how? (I'm at a loss.)

Edit: Clarification on whitespace:

If we say that a "whitespace object" is simply a string and read, then `read`ing the following segment:

```
(foo bar   baz)
```

produces a syntax object like:

```
'(foo " " bar "   " baz)
```

In other words, the whitespace between tokens is stored in the resultant syntax object.

Suppose I write a macro named ->, which takes a syntax object (scheme style macro), and `whitespace?` is a predicate identifying whitespace syntax objects

```
(define-macro (-> stx)
  (let* ((stxl (syntax-object->list stx))
         (obj (car stxl))
     (let proc ((res empty))
                (lst (cdr stxl)))
       (let ((method (car lst)))
          (if (whitespace? method)
              ; skip whitespace, recur immediately
              (proc res (cdr lst))
              ; Insert obj as the second element in method
              (let ((modified-method (cons (car method)
                                           (cons obj (cdr method)))))
                ; recur
                (proc (cons res modified-method) (cdr lst))))))))
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Whitespace is read and is part of the resulting syntax." Can you provide an example that demonstrates this aspect?

Comment: I think you're asking for a few different things here.  The lexing/parsing part if relatively straightforward, I think.  You just need to write a lexer that produces the tokens you're looking for, and then write the parser that assembles them into a result.  Your later thing about line-based input sounds like a different function where you'd do **read-line** and then read all the expressions from the line, and if there's more than one, or there's just one, but it's note a list, you'd put the the result into a list.  Your evaluator, though, would need to be a genuinely new thing.

Comment: I've added an example. A whitespace object is similar to a symbol, except it consists only of whitespace characters, and it is ignored by the evaluator instead of looking up the symbol.

Comment: About the evaluator, you mention that "whitespace objects" are ignored during evaluation.  What happens with something like `'(<whitespace object>)`?  Is that the empty list?  Is it a function call?  Now, all of a sudden, you have some weird things in your expressions.  What does `(eval '<whitespace-object>)` return?  How about `(eval '(list <whitespace-object>))`?

Comment: Yes, I know I can do it, my question is can it be done in a way that obeys the typical contract of a lisp read procedure (i.e. read one expression at a time from a mutable input stream)?

Comment: `'(<ws>)` evaluates exactly as `'()`. I mentioned in the OP that `'<ws>` is self-evaluating, it produces `<ws>`. `(eval '(list <ws>))` evaluates as `(eval '(list))`.

Comment: The purpose of the whitespace object is for macros, which are processed before they are evaluated, so a macro would have the opportunity to be whitespace-sensitive if it wanted to.

Comment: I think my answer shows how you can do this relatively easily with a macro character.  You might find the discussion in [How to define symbols that will work like ( and ) by symbol macro?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19319277/how-to-define-symbols-that-will-work-like-and-by-symbol-macro/19321377#19321377) useful, as well.

Answer (score 3):

The reading part of this is pretty easy.  You just need a whitespace test, and then your reading function will install a custom reader character macro that detects whitespace and reads consecutive sequences of whitespace into a single object.  First, the whitespace test and a whitespace object;  these are pretty simple:

```
(defparameter *whitespace*
  #(#\space #\tab #\return #\newline)
  "A vector of whitespace characters.")

(defun whitespace-p (char)
  "Returns true if CHAR is in *WHITESPACE*."
  (find char *whitespace* :test 'char=))

(defstruct whitespace-object
  characters)
```

Now the macro character function:

```
(defun whitespace-macro-char (stream char)
  "A macro character function that consumes characters from
stream (including CHAR), until a non-whitespace character (or end of
file) is encountered.  Returns a whitespace-object whose characters
slot contains a string of the whitespace characters."
  (let ((chars (loop for c = (peek-char nil stream nil #\a)
                  while (whitespace-p c)
                  collect (read-char stream))))
    (make-whitespace-object
     :characters (coerce (list* char chars) 'string))))
```

Now the read function just has the same signature as the normal **read**, but copies the readtable, then installs the macro function, and calls **read**.  The result from **read** is returned, and the readtable is restored:

```
(defun xread (&optional (stream *standard-input*) (eof-error-p t) eof-value recursive-p)
  "Like READ, but called with *READTABLE* bound to a readtable in
which each whitespace characters (that is, each character in
*WHITESPACE*) is a macro characters whose macro function is
WHITESPACE-MACRO-CHAR."
  (let ((rt (copy-readtable)))
    (map nil (lambda (wchar)
               (set-macro-character wchar #'whitespace-macro-char))
         *whitespace*)
    (unwind-protect (read stream eof-error-p eof-value recursive-p)
      (setf *readtable* rt))))
```

Example:

```
(with-input-from-string (in "(+ 1    2  (* 3    
                                         4))")
  (xread in))

(+ #S(WHITESPACE-OBJECT :CHARACTERS " ") 1
   #S(WHITESPACE-OBJECT :CHARACTERS "    ") 2
   #S(WHITESPACE-OBJECT :CHARACTERS "  ")
   (* #S(WHITESPACE-OBJECT :CHARACTERS " ") 3
      #S(WHITESPACE-OBJECT
         :CHARACTERS "  
                                         ")
      4))
```

Now, to implement the **eval** counterpart that you want, you need to be able to remove whitespace objects from lists.  This isn't too hard, and we can write a slightly more general utility function to do it for us:

```
(defun remove-element-if (predicate tree)
  "Returns a new tree like TREE, but which contains no elements in an
element position which ssatisfy PREDICATE.  An element is in element
position if it is the car of some cons cell in TREE."
  (if (not (consp tree))
      tree
      (if (funcall predicate (car tree))
          (remove-element-if predicate (cdr tree))
          (cons (remove-element-if predicate (car tree))
                (remove-element-if predicate (cdr tree))))))
```

```
CL-USER> (remove-element-if (lambda (x) (and (numberp x) (evenp x))) '(+ 1 2 3 4))
(+ 1 3)
```

```
CL-USER> (with-input-from-string (in "(+ 1  2 (* 3
                                                 4))")
           (remove-element-if 'whitespace-object-p (xread in)))
(+ 1 2 (* 3 4))
```

So now the evaluation function is a simple wrapper around **eval**:

```
(defun xeval (form)
  (eval (remove-element-if 'whitespace-object-p form)))
```

```
CL-USER> (with-input-from-string (in "(+ 1  2 (* 3
                                                 4))")
           (xeval (xread in)))
15
```

Let's make sure that standalone whitespace objects still appear as expected:

```
CL-USER> (with-input-from-string (in "       ")
           (let* ((exp (xread in))
                  (val (xeval exp)))
             (values exp val)))
#S(WHITESPACE-OBJECT :CHARACTERS "       ")
#S(WHITESPACE-OBJECT :CHARACTERS "       ")
```

Comment: Yeah, the problem arises when you try to combine this with the "multiple elements on one line form a list" rule. To read such a rule, I would read whitespace, then read the "solid" token, then read whitespace again and look for an end-of-line. If the peek char is non-whitespace then we have a list and I can read that list without violating the "one expression per read" rule, but if not, then I've read two expressions: The "solid" token and the "whitespace" token. Is it possible to implement both rules? Even with a fully custom read procedure, beyond a readtable modification.

Comment: @MattG I wasn't really sure what to make of *"Secondly, if several tokens other than whitespace tokens appear on the same line, those tokens are collected into a list and that list is the result of the read."*  what happens when a single expression spans multiple lines?  E.g., is something like `(op <newline> a b <newline> c d)` supposed to be read as `(op (a b) c d)`?  or `((op) (ab) (c d))`?  None of your examples showed any multi-line input, so I'd assumed that the line-by-line processing was for something else, wherein you'd just use read-line to read a line, then call xread to collect

Comment: expressions.  If there's just one expression, then if it's a list, and if it's not, return a list containing it.  If there are multiple expression, just return the list of all of them.

Comment: In order to have a multiple-line expression, you have to use parens. If a list is opened but hasn't been closed by the end of the line, then reading the list continues until it closes. So `foo bar \n baz qux` is `(foo bar) \n (baz qux)` but `foo (bar \n baz) qux` is `(foo (bar baz) qux)` and `foo (bar \n baz) \n qux` is `(foo (bar baz)) (qux)`

Comment: @Matt OK, so when **xread** starts, it has to read expressions until a newline or EOF is encountered.  Is that right?  E.g,. if you see `foo \n bar`, you can stop at `\n`.  If you see `foo (bar \n baz) quux \n frob`. you'd read `foo`, then `bar \n \baz`, then `quux`, then hit the newline, so you'd be left with `(foo (bar baz quux))`.  I don't think that's too hard; let me take a stab at it.

Comment: Well, the typical rule for a read procedure, as far as I know in every lisp, is that if you're reading an atom, you read only one atom, and if you're reading a list, you read that entire list but nothing else. So if `!!!` marks the place where reading stops, then: `foo!!! bar` but `(foo bar)!!! baz`. Since in most lisps whitespace is not significant, you're also allowed to read as much whitespace as you want, but since in this reader whitespace forms tokens, you can't read it, only peek it (non-mutating operation on the stream)

Comment: @MattG I'm confident that this can be implemented in a way that respects the usual contract that **read** follows (i.e., the only input removed from the stream is that which makes up the expression that was read), but I think you'll need to pin down the grammar more precisely first.  What's does `(a b) c \n d` produce?  `((a b) c) (d)`?  Or `(a b) (c) (d)`?  What about `let (a 1 \n b 2) x \n`?  Does it produce `(let ((a 1) (b 2) (x))` or `(let (a 1 b2) x)`?  Why?

Comment: for brevity, I'm not including whitespace objects.
`(a b) c \n d` -> `((a b) c) d`
because first line is multiple tokens, which are listed, and second line is one token, which is not.
`let (a 1 \n b 2) \n x` ->  `(let (a 1 b 2)) x`
because `let (a 1` tells us we're building a list (multiple exprs), but the paren isn't closed, so we have to continue reading until it is closed, and then there is a newline so we end the list there

Comment: @MattG You copied the \n into a different place in my second query.  `let (a  1 \n b 2) x \n`.  The `x` is *before* the newline.  Would you get `(let (a 1 b 2) x)` or `(let (a 1 b 2)) x`?

Comment: The reason I'm asking so much about the multi line stuff is that you're trying to get closer to a whitespace-significant DSL, it seems like it'd be beneficial to treat all newlines the same, i.e., as terminating whatever's been read since the last "opening", with the exception/addition that actual parentheses can introduce multi-line grouping.  It seems like what you're looking for is actually something where newlines inside of lists don't matter.

Comment: Both of those would be accurate, and to correct myself: `let (a 1 \n b 2) x \n` -> `(let (a 1 b 2) x)` because the \n in `1 \n b` is between parens so we ignore it